# ExtJS 5.1: Setting default ComboBox value using MVVM store

Tags: extjs, combobox, extjs5

In my ViewModel, I create an inline data store for a ComboBox that I bind to in the View. The problem that I'm having is setting a default value for the ComboBox, based on one of the values in the store... I might be understanding binding here, so I'd like to hear any feedback.

OrderDetailsStatus model:

```
Ext.define('UserUI.model.OrderDetailsStatus', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    alias: 'model.OrderDetailsStatus',

    fields: [{
        type: 'int',
        name: 'statusId'
    },
    {
        type: 'string',
        name: 'status'
    }]
});
```

ViewModel:

```
stores: {
        /* TODO: This could eventually become an AJAX call, but for right now,
         * it's an inline data store... the statusId's are currently unused */
        orderDetailsStatusStore: {
            model: 'UserUI.model.OrderDetailsStatus',
            proxy: {
                type: 'memory'
            },
            data: [
                { status: 'All', statusId: 1 },
                { status: 'Correct', statusId: 2 },
                { status: 'Incorrect', statusId: 3 }
            ]
        }
    }
```

In the View:

```
{
                xtype: 'combo',
                fieldLabel: 'Status',
                bind: {
                    store: '{orderDetailsStatusStore}'
                },
                valueField: 'status',
                displayField: 'status',
                queryMode: 'local',
                value: 'All',
                listeners: {
                    select: 'onSelectComboBoxStatus'
                }
            }
```

Using the value: 'All' gives me an error about the model not existing:

```
TypeError: Model is not a constructor: ext-all...ebug.js (line 122343, col 33)
    record = new Model(dataObj);
```

I'm assuming this is because the bound store hasn't been fully loaded in yet?  If I debug the code, at that line, Model is undefined, and the store doesn't have any data. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Fiddle updated with fix in 5.1.0**

```html
<iframe src="https://fiddle.sencha.com/fiddle/m3g"></iframe>
```

I've created a simple fiddle that replicates yours - 
https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/m3g

Comment: Interesting... if you change it to use version 5.1, you'll see my error.  (see [this fork](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/m3c))

Comment: The store is already loaded, as it's inline data... if Ext sees `data` it doesn't need `autoLoad`.

Comment: I'm actually wondering if it's related to [this thread](https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?285643-Default-Combobox-value-not-selected) and if it's a bug.

Comment: I'm trying to check with the nightly builds.

Comment: @incutonez - suggest you update your question to 5.1 :)

Comment: OK - try this fiddle again - https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/m3b - I've used a nightly build and it's working. 15th April Nightly build.

Comment: updated title, but there's no 5.1 tag yet.  Looks like I'll just have to wait for 5.1.1.  Thanks.

Comment: Or, you could debug the changes and apply some overrides :)